# How to exit emacs with `q` when man inside emacs is opened

Tags: emacsclient, man

Default behavior of `man <command>` (opens inside `less`) when `q` is pressed it is closed.

---

I am using following to open [`MANPAGER` with `emacs`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59462/can-i-set-manpager-to-open-a-man-page-with-emacs/59587?noredirect=1#comment93379_59587):

`emacsclient -nw -e "(let ((Man-notify-method 'bully)) (man \"$1\"))"`

Here pressing `q` closes buffer but does not close the `emacs` like `Ctrl-x Ctrl-c` does. Is it possible to bind `q` into the same action `Ctrl-x Ctrl-c` to exit the `emacs` and get back to shell.

Comment: Given that you want to use your Emacs session as a presentation layer for `man`, I would think you'd be better off setting `Man-notify-method` to `newframe` and then exiting by using `C-x 5 0`.  You could even set a single key like `Q` (upper case) to `delete-frame`.  That way you would never accidentally leave Emacs altogether - since `q` is such a useful key in many modes

Comment: I think you are right! Becase when I click to a linked man page, it opens it on other window and clicking `q` closes that opened buffer. Instead to be more clear `Q` could be used, which also exists on the Man page via `less`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the incantation you want is

```
(define-key Man-mode-map "q" 'save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

I am guessing that you can do this inside your let form.

```
emacsclient -nw -e "(let ((Man-notify-method 'bully)) (man \"$1\") (define-key Man-mode-map \"q\" 'save-buffers-kill-emacs))"
```

Comment: `save-buffers-kill-terminal` is going to kill emacs and kill the terminal which is why I suggested `save-buffers-kill-emacs`.

Comment: Ah my bad I confused them. //Lets say I did `man printf` and click to `printf(3)` at the bottom of the page right under `SEE ALSO`. At this point, when I press `q` instead of doing `save-buffers-kill-terminal` can it also do its default behaviour which is only to close one of the buffer?

Comment: I think that typing `k` will kill just the buffer you are viewing. When you are viewing a man page in emacs type `C-h m` to find all the things you can do in `Man-mode`.

Comment: Thanks @Aidan Schofield

Comment: The `*-kill-emacs` function kills the Emacs process, so for client processes you may want to use `save-buffers-kill-terminal`.